Text in table with vertical spanning not wrapping
I have a table which uses horizontal and vertical spanning of table cells (the MWE only includes horizontal spanning). I want the table to fully span the \textwidth of the document. Hence, I am ussing XXX for the colspec. The table contains short pieces of content and long pieces of content, the latter spanning over multiple columns as shown in the MWE.
The problem I'm facing is that the text does not wrap, but just goes of the page. How can I fix this? I would prefer a solution that does not require to edit the text in the cells themselves (as the real table is longer and this would be time consuming), so nothing like manual line breaking.
The promised MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
    \begin{tblr}{
            hlines,
            vlines,
            colspec = XXX,
            cell{2}{2} = {c=2}{},
        }

        1 & 2          & 3 \\
        4 & \lipsum[1] & 6
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}

The result:

Help would be appreciated!

If it is an option for you: I use \parbox for linebreak in a table in combination with fixed columns widths with p{5cm} for example. It works with your example, although it requires some adjustments.

@Tom this works reasonably well, however, I would prefer an option with relative column widths (using the X specifier) and without having to manually tweak the contents in the table itself.

Here is a solution using hspan=minimal:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tblr}{
    vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
    hlines,
    vlines,
    colspec = XXX,
    cell{2}{2} = {c=2}{},
    }
    
    1 & 2          & 3 \\
    4 & \lipsum[1] & 6
  \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Note: Cell fusion to be “natural” requires hspan=minimal and vspan=even.

This seems to work better than the solution I accepted earlier, however, what exactly is the point of vspan here?

@Texnicallyausername Here, vspan is not needed. But these options are the ones I recommend because they usually produce the desired result for cell merge operations.

Similar to other tabular environments, you need to help tabularray a bit in such cases and state the width of the multicolumn cell explicitly, which is ⅔ of the \linewidth (or \textwidth in this case) minus the left and right cell sep (6pt each per default) minus twice the border (0.4pt per default). You should also tell it to align the contents of the cell (actually of all cells) justified (j):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tblr}{
            hlines,
            vlines,
            colspec = {X[j] X[j] X[j]},
            cell{2}{2} = {c=2}{j,0.67\linewidth-12.8pt},
        }
        1 & 2          & 3 \\
        4 & \lipsum[1] & 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}



A bit frustrating, but this is probably the closest to what I'm after. Cheers!

@Texnicallyausername Maybe I overlooked something, but I think this is the most straight-forward way.

@JasperHabicht Adding the draft option shows that the table extends into the margin.

@JasperHabicht Warning: Overfull \hbox (13.01604pt too wide)...

@PaulGaborit Seems like the token variables do not hold the right values at this time. \leftsep+\rightsep+2\rulewidth should be exactly 12.8pt, but it is not. So, maybe I should delete this answer ...

Since this solution has that problem and I think the solution by @PaulGaborit is more elegant, I've accepted his solution as the answer.
